# String-based queries like [executeUpdate] are currently not supported in integration test environment

Tags: grails, hql

I am trying to run test cases in an integration test environment.

In service, `executeUpdate` has been used:

```
def update1 = Abc.executeUpdate("update Abc a set a.changeStatus = :status,a.remarks=:remarks where a.id =:id",[status: "Verified",id:1,remarks:remarks])
```

But while running the integration test of the service I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: String-based queries like
>   [executeUpdate] are currently not supported in this implementation of
>   GORM. Use criteria instead.

I am using **Grails 2.4.2**.

Comment: Are you sure that your test is Integration? Because this error I had only in unit. Show your test code, please

Comment: @Koloritnij Yes, the test is integration. But looking at your comment, I came to realise that I had been using annotations like 'TestFor' and 'Mock' which are most likely the annotations of unit test and may be its because of their bad behaviours that I was getting error. Now, I have solved this problem. Thank you .

Comment: you are welcome, hope grails would be your prefered framework ;)